# Pam not authenticating properly php

Tags: php, pam

I was trying to make a website that authenticates with the local unix accounts of the server but `pam_auth` always returns `false` i.e. I always get `Welcome error` when I submit the form.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
            <form id="a" method="post" action="welcome.php">
                    <input name="user" type="text">
                    <input name="pass" type="password">
                    <button type="submit">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

welcome.php:

```
<html>
    <body>
            <p>Welcome
            <?php
                    if(pam_auth($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) {
                            echo $_POST['user'];
                    } else {
                            echo "error";
                    }
             ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any replies are much appreciated.